# iterative reweighted least squares

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

I am trying to manually implement the irls logistic regression (Chapter 4.3.3 in [Bishop - Pattern Recognition And Machine Learning](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A1783%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Fit%22%7D%5D)) in python. 
For updating the weights, I am using [image: newton-raphson update formula]
However I am not getting satisfying results, also my weights are growing unbounded in each iteration.

I've written this code so far:

```
def y(X, w):
    return sigmoid(X.dot(w))

def R(y):
    R = np.identity(y.size)
    R = R*(y*(1-y))
    return R

def irls(X, t):
    w = np.ones(X.shape[1])
    w = w.reshape(w.size, 1)
    t = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 1 if x else 0, t)))
    t = t.reshape(t.size, 1)

    #after 3 iterations matrix is singular
    for i in range(3):
        y_ = y(X,w)
        w = w - np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(R(y_)).dot(X)).dot((X.T).dot(y_-t))
    return w
```

where X is my design matrix (64 features and 74 samples) and t is my target vector comprising Boolean values (data is from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Mice+Protein+Expression).

Any help is appreciated pointing out where I went wrong.

Answer (score -1):

So the answer is as simple as setting the initial weight vector `w = np.zeros(X.shape[1)`